# Laravel sort by join value many to many relationship with pagination

Tags: sorting, laravel, model

Lets say that each user has domains and I would like to be able to display those domains in a tabular format.

As a user I should be able to sort by the domain attributes.

The domain attributes include sortable entities such as page rank.

In laravel I grab a collection of domains that are related to the currently logged in user like so:

```
            $users = User::with(array('domains' => function($query)
            {
//                    $query->where('name','like','%all%'); //subquery filter

            }))->whereId(Session::get('user')['id'])->first();


        if(isset($sort))
        {
            //What goes here?
        }
```

I can itterate through the results like so:

```
 $domains = $users->domains;

$collection = Paginator::make($domains->toArray(), $page, $pagesize);
```

To get the result set I would do this:

```
$collection->getItems();
```

How do I apply a filter to the domain results to apply sorting by a particular value?

Answer (score 0):

So I got done typing this message and decided to try something:

```
public function listView()
    {

        $order = Input::get('order') === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'; // default desc
        $page = Input::get('page') ? Input::get('page') : 1; // default 1

        $model = new Domain;

        $pagesize = Input::get('pagesize');


        if(isset($pagesize))
        {
            if($pagesize == 'all')
            {
                $pagesize = count($model::all());
            }elseif(!is_numeric($pagesize))
            {
             $pagesize =  DomainsController::$default_pagesize;
            }
        }else{
            $pagesize =  DomainsController::$default_pagesize;
        }




        $users = User::with(array('domains' => function($query)
            {
                $sort = Input::get('sort') ? Input::get('sort') : NULL; // default NULL
                $order = Input::get('order') ? Input::get('order') : 'DESC'; // default DESC
                if(isset($sort))
                {
                    $query->orderBy($sort, $order);
                }

            }))->whereId(Session::get('user')['id'])->first();





        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        $last_query = end($queries);



        $domains = $users->domains;




        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        $last_query = end($queries);
        var_dump($last_query);

        $collection = Paginator::make($domains->toArray(), $page, $pagesize);


        $data = array(
            'totalCount' => count($domains),
            'pageSize' => $collection->getPerPage(),
            'numberOfPages' => $collection->getLastPage(),
            'currentPage' => $collection->getCurrentPage(),
            'startNumber' => $collection->getFrom(),
            'endNumber' => $collection->getTo(),
            'results' => $collection->getItems(),
            'sortstr'=>((Input::get('pagesize')) ==  '' ? '' : '&pagesize='.(Input::get('pagesize'))).'&order='.($order == 'asc' || null ? 'desc' : 'asc'),
            'querystr'=>(Input::get('pagesize')) ==  '' ? '' : '&pagesize='.(Input::get('pagesize')).'&order='.(Input::get('order') == '' ? 'desc' : (Input::get('order')))
        );


        $this->layout->content = View::make('pages.domains.list',$data);
    }
```

This is working code.

To answer my own question, the problem I was having is simply that the $sort value was inaccessible from the function SEE function($query).